# Tub drain takes time to drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, cleaning, bathtub, blockage

The house I shifted into recently was built in 2016; I have lived here for six weeks and don't know the place yet. Before moving in, I had the plumber check all the pipes and drains. After shifting, I have used liquid products to clean the drain. The drain looks unclogged and flows well for some time. Then, when I run water 30 minutes later, it's almost wholly blocked again and takes several minutes to drain. I've a problem with the tub drain mostly, which is slow to drain. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

With a slow drain on a tub I would pull the drain and you will probably bring up a wad of hair and soap scum. I have to do this several times a year as my wife, daughters and most of my granddaughters have very long hair. There are wrenches to pull the drain you can purchase for 10$ I use screwdrivers most of the time even though I have multiple basin wrenches I always have a couple of screwdrivers handy. I put 2 in the drain hold them with 1 hand then use a 3rd or something between them and turn, a few turns counter clockwise and it is usually loose enough to finish unscrewing, pull up and usually a wad of hair comes up. My tub has a rubber seal so I just re use that after putting the wad of hair in the trash if you have a paste like substance or it may be sealed with plumbers putty and best practice is to replace it putty is cheap and a 1/2 pint last forever. If you want to try and re use scrape it up roll it into “worm” slight longer than the length around the drain opening. Over lap the ends pinch then put the drain back in when you hit bottom pause then tighten if putty squished out that is usually tight enough.

As for backing up after 30 minutes that would probably be an issue far down the line and a newer home possibly a main drain broken or a septic system that is getting water logged.

Answer (score 0):

HOW did you use liquid products to clear the drain?  How much?

You have a clog pretty far down in the pipe somewhere.  If I were you I would go to HD and buy 3 gallons of the cheapest drain opener (they sell it for around $10 a gallon) and I would then give the drain an hour to clear and then dump all 3 bottles into it.  You want it getting far enough into the pipe to reach the clog and saturate the clog.

If that does not work then it will need to be snaked all the way to the street.

Comment: I would also check for hair in the stopper mechanism.